# How to call individual form fields in Django templates that have the same name?

Tags: python, django, templates

This is how I would call a individual form field:

```
{{ form.product }}
```

This would display only the form element with the name "product". But what about in the case of radio buttons or checkboxes where multiple form fields have the same name. How do I call one over another then?

Is there a way to use value instead of name or some other distinguishing id?

P.S. please don't post any python code suggestions. I am a front end developer and have access to only template tags, filters and variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to work more closely with your Python developers :-)

Basically, if the case were to arise where there are multiple radio buttons/checkboxes with the same name, they should be easily provided to you under the form, using the same schema you're using already.

So, make sure your developer gives you access to all the form elements you need. If they're creating a widget that spits out 4 different radio buttons, you should be able to call them using the way you've done it already, `form.some_radio_buttons`

Nothing special, just a matter of the backend developer giving you the right information.

Comment: Yea, sadly there isn't any Django magic that will just make this work. You'll need to use python and tell it the form objects you want to send to the template.

Comment: I can call all the radio buttons at the same time, but I just want to be able to call them individually to put them int he right places of the form design. @Bryce Siedschlaw darn, ok thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Maybe you didn't quite understand bartek. What he's saying is that you can't call form objects by their value, only their name. However, your backend devs can create different types of fields with different names like form.product_text and form.product_radio... stuff like that to make it easier for their front end devs. Also, if they really wanted to, they could have some settings and then dynamically create the form fields to whatever the user would like to see.